# python stops working in the middle of dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a script to read and plot data into the graphs. I have three input files

- wells.csv: list of observation wells that I want to create graph

  1201

  1202

  ...
- well_summary_table.csv: contained information for each well (e.g. reference elevation, depth to water)

  Bore_Name     Ref_elev

  1201            20
- data.csv: contained observation data for each well (e.g. pH, Temp)

  RowId    Bore_Name     Depth     pH

  1          1201           2        7

Not all wells in wells.csv have data to plot

My script is as follow

```
well_name_list = []
new_depth_list =[]
pH_list = []
from pylab import *
infile = open("wells.csv",'r')
for line in infile:
    line=line.strip('\n')
    well=line
    if not well in well_name_list:
        well_name_list.append(well)
infile.close()
for well in well_name_list:
    infile1 = open("well_summary_table.csv",'r')
    infile2 = open("data.csv",'r')
    for line in infile1:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line.startswith('Bore_Name'):
            words = line.split(',')
            well_name1 = words[0]
            if well_name1 == well:
                ref_elev = words[1]
    for line in infile2:
        if not line.startswith("RowId"):
            line = line.strip('\n')
            words = line.split(',')
            well_name2 = words[1]
            if well_name2 == well:
                depth = words[2]
                new_depth = float(ref_elev) - float(depth)
                pH = words[3]
                new_depth_list.append(float(new_depth))
                pH_list.append(float(pH))
                fig.plt.figure(figsize = (2,2.7), facecolor='white')
                plt.axis([0,8,0,60])
                plt.plot(pH_list, new_depth_list, linestyle='', marker = 'o')
                plt.savefig(well+'.png')
    new_depth_list = []
    pH_list = []
infile1.close()
infile2.close()
```

It works on more than half of my well list then it stops without giving me any error message. I don't know what is going on. Can anyone help me with that problem? Sorry if it is an obvious question. I am a newbie.

Many thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "stops"? Does the program exit, or are only half of the figures saved, or something else? Does it stop at the same point each time? Try `print`ing out the well name to see where it stops if you don't already know

Comment: close `infile1` and `infile2` in your `for well...` loop. Or better yet use a context manager (http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Comment: other than that, this is a bit of a mess of data parsing which is hard to debug with out your full data set.  If it is not too big I would suggest parsing yours files once and saving it to an in-memory data structure and then plotting off of that.

Comment: because I ask python to print well name on the screen when it go through each well. I saw it get to more than half of my well in the list then it seems not doing any further. It doesn't continue to print well name on the screen anymore.

Comment: I've tried to close file before plotting my graph and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

@tcaswell spotted a potential issue - you aren't closing `infile1` and `infile2` after each time you open them - you'll at the very least have a lot of open file handles floating around, depending on how many wells you have in the `wells.csv` file. In some versions of python this may cause issues, but this may not be the only problem - it's hard to say without some test data files. There might be an issue with seeking to the start of the file - going back to the beginning when you move on to the next well. This could cause the program to run as you've been experiencing, but it might also be caused by something else. You should avoid problems like this by using `with` to manage the scope of your open files.

You should also use a dictionary to marry up the well names with the data, and read all of the data up front before doing your plotting. This will allow you to see exactly how you've constructed your data set and where any issues exist.

I've made a few stylistic suggestions below too. This is obviously incomplete but hopefully you get the idea!

```
import csv
from pylab import * #imports should always go before declarations
well_details = {} #empty dict

with open('wells.csv','r') as well_file:
    well_reader = csv.reader(well_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in well_reader:
        well_name = row[0]
        if not well_details.has_key(well_name):
            well_details[well_name] = {} #dict to store pH, depth, ref_elev

with open('well_summary_table.csv','r') as elev_file:
    elev_reader = csv.reader(elev_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in elev_reader:
        well_name = row[0]
        if well_details.has_key(well_name):
            well_details[well_name]['elev_ref'] = row[1]
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is the answer, because the OP re-opens them at the top of the loop every time.

Comment: @tcaswell but is that statement closing and reopening the file (probably not), doing the equivalent of `seek(0)`,discarding pointers to open file and replacing them with others,  or something else? It's poor practice and undefined behaviour, and building up a data sctructure of the information to plot has the bonus of printability / readability. Even if it doesn't explicitly solve the problem, my bet is it'll either go away or be plainly obvious if the questioner refactors their code.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you said, but at least on 2.7 it 'does the right thing' and will give you back the result you naively expect (suspect it is just opening a new file handle each time). My only complaint is the claim that failing to properly close the files is the root problem.

Comment: @tcaswell Fair enough. I'll improve my answer to reflect this. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How can I add another key to well_details dictionary? because I will need salinity values for different depths for each well. So I think I need to have both well name and depth as keys

Comment: @Amylee You could store another dict for salinities: `well_details[well_name]['salinity'] = {}` and then have the depth as the key and the salinity as the value. `well_details[well_name]['salinity'][depth] = salinity_value`

Comment: Just another qs. After creating all my graphs, I want to put 10 of them in one page (.pdf) and continue through all of my graphs. Can I do it using pdfPages? I've tried that but it give me one pdf file with each of my graph is in one page. Many thanks

Comment: @Amylee you could create one `figure` with 9 (3x3) plots, using `subplot(33x)` where `x` is 1-9 and indexes into the 3x3 grid. If you search on stackoverflow there are plenty of answers on using `subplot` like this. Hope this helps!